# how to make that app requires internet connection

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads

I am making an android app in unity3d. I have added ads but when internet connection on device is off the ads don`t display. It`s ok but I wanna make that app will not run when is not internet. I have been searching and checking many solution but nothing. Maybe someone had similar problem, thanx for help.

Comment: This is confusing. You want make that app work when is no internet or don't wan it to work when there is no internet connection?

Comment: Doesn't android have an "Is Net Connected" status somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to make a simple server/hosted endpoint somewhere that your application calls out to on startup. If the endpoint is able to be reached and a valid response is received, the application can continue to run, otherwise you exit the application.

This technique is a good start, but many client-side limitations like this can be circumvented by a skilled/dedicated attacked, so relying on this method alone would not be enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is this:

```
    // Detects if there is no internet and sends to Error Scene
    if ((Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable) &&
        (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Error"))
    {
        Debug.Log("There is no internet");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Error", "No Internet");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ErrorId", 1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Error");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is use this method when the app start to check connection:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

Don't forget declare permission in Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```